# How can I generate a excel report from a database?

Tags: php, database, excel

I posted code about this earlier today, but it's old code that the app has now and I can't figure it out. So want to start fresh. Is there a way to generate a report from a table on a database and do it in excel. It would select course _ date and course _ Id as the main data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP excel library for generating excel reports.
https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/